# ROR editor from a video

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just came across a tutorial on sending emails using rails.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/61-sending-email?autoplay=true

I really liked the editor. What the name of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Textmate](http://macromates.com/).  FYI, not sure of your platform, but it is only available for Mac OSX.

Comment: There's e-TextEditor for the PC/Linux that tries to do the same: http://www.e-texteditor.com/

Comment: Indeed.  I've had minimal experience with it - didn't 'do it' for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is `Textmate` for MAC OS.